# How to Loop through the range and assign value to parameter

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am facing an issue regarding Excel VBA code and hoping that anyone can help me on this.

I have an Excel column which is Range B2 until the last row of column B as below:

```
_________________
|Column B Header|
|===============|
|apple          |
|orange         |
|strawberry     |
|blueberry      |
|_______________|
```

I want to assign all the value in cell B into a parameter with some additional text.

For example :

```
fruits = <Item>apple</Item><Item>orange</Item><Item>strawberry</Item><Item>blueberry</Item>
```

This is my code so far, I have difficulty to make each value to continue at behind after each cell read.

```
Dim c As Range
For each c In Range("B2:B" & lastrow)
   fruits = "<Item>" & c.Value & "</Item>"
Next c
```

I really appreciate it if anyone willing to help me on this.
Thanks.

Comment: `fruits = fruits & "<Item>" & c.Value & "</Item>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To continue building up the string as you loop, concatenate `fruits` with itself:

```
fruits = fruits & "<Item>" & c.Value & "</Item>"
```

Answer (score 2):

or you can avoid looping

```
Dim fruits As String
fruits = "<Item>" & Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value), "|"), "|", "</Item><Item>") & "</Item>"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Function without loops plus variable tag name**

```
Function JoinedItems(rng As Range, Optional tag As String = "item") As String
    Dim a$, b$: a = "<" & tag & ">": b = "</" & tag & ">"
    JoinedItems = a & Evaluate("=TEXTJOIN(""" & b & a & """, False," & rng.Address & ")") & b
End Function
```